# how to detect why my .net web app is pegging cpu at 100% intermittently?

Tags: asp.net

I have a large (as in many pages, objects...) asp.net web app that pegs the server at 100% at times for no reason that i can tell. is there a way to detect what page is at fault?

I know its asp.net and not sql because task manager shows w3wp.exe as the culprit.

are there tools for doing this? or profiling .net web apps?

Comment: Ask this over at serverfault (or flag it asking an admin to do that).  Windows Server has performance counters that might benefit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this Red Gate product: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

It's not trivial to master, though.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net Tracing is the answer.

http://www.asp101.com/articles/robert/tracing/default.asp

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-implement-tracing-in-an-aspnet-web-site

[image]
<sub>(source: [asp101.com](http://www.asp101.com/articles/robert/tracing/images/trace_information.jpg))</sub>

Comment: this wont help me unless i manual start clicking around and reading the trace. I need it to give me a read-out of user actions and effects on the server so i can correlate actions to server cpu usage

Answer (score 0):

If you can repeat the issue on a test server or you own machine you can use a profiler (the one included in Visual Studio 2010 or any other) to figure out what's happening.

If the problem only occurs in production you probably are best off performing a dump of the process when the problem is occuring and [analyze it using DebugDiag](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919791).

[Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) has lots of information on her blog on how to perform low level analysis of application behaviour on her blog as well, including how to use DebugDiag.

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't by chance happening to be using `GC.Collect()` in your web app would you?   Excessive calls to `GC.Collect()` for large applications will cause it to spike to 100% as it scans memory to look for disposable objects.   If you call `GC.Collect()` in rapid succession, you would likely get a continuous 100% cpu usage when memory usage is high.

Comment: Oh well so much for low hanging fruit.  Other things to perhaps examine are any LARGE Datasets that are being thrown around, large XSL transforms, or other passing around of potentially large amounts of information